# Apache Flink: root cause exception from Flink UI is not visible in logs

Tags: logging, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a flink job running and configured to log with logback config, weird issue is that when an exception happen, the root cause exception that I can find in flink web ui is not found in the files log or console logs.

Any help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.